# @DiscriminatorColumn/@DiscriminatorValue is not working

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, discriminator

I have this class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOO")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="IS_FOO_OR_BAR", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.CHAR)
@DiscriminatorValue("FOO")
public final class FOO {
  ...
}
```

But when I use `findAll()` with Spring Data JPA, the results contains foo and bar values in the discriminant.

I also tried to create an abstract parent class, with `@MappedSuperclass` but same result.

What am I doing wrong?

I am working with Spring Data JPA, JPA 2.1, Hibernate 5.1.0, and I tried my request in H2Database and in Oracle.

Edit (The sql invoked by jpa provider):

```
select FOO.* FROM FOO
```

It's like i am missing a where condition.

Edit 2 :

I added the @DiscriminatorOptions(force = true) and now it works.
But when i try to use an abstract class it's not working.
The where condition is absent...

pojo :

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="IF_FOO_OR_BAR", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.CHAR,columnDefinition = "char(1) default 'N'")
@DiscriminatorOptions(force = true)
public abstract class AbstractFoo {
    ....
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "FOO")
@DiscriminatorValue("FOO")
public final class Foo extends AbstractFoo {
  ...
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "FOO")
@DiscriminatorValue("BAR")
public final class Bar extends AbstractFoo {
  ...
}
```

Comment: why not start by looking at the SQL invoked by the JPA provider? the first step in debugging any communication with the database

Comment: That code doesn't make much sense. How could you have a Bar subclass if your Foo class is final? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am using it as a test to see if discriminatorColumn is working. I added @DiscriminatorOptions(force = true) to my entity and now it gives me the correct results.

Comment: why are you declaring your entities as final? as of JPA-documentation: "The entity class must not be final. No methods or persistent instance variables of the entity class may be
final."

Comment: Thanks ! @DiscriminatorOptions(force = true) works !

Answer (score 0):

Add `@DiscriminatorOptions(force = true)` in your main entity.

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="IF_FOO_OR_BAR", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.CHAR,columnDefinition = "char(1) default 'N'")
@DiscriminatorOptions(force = true)
public abstract class AbstractFoo {
    ....
}
```